# How to migrate schema using Flyway into a docker container database to create an isolated testing environment?

Tags: mysql, docker, unit-testing, docker-compose, flyway

I want to migrate the schemas I have for the tables in my db into a docker container I've made. First time using flyway and it seems entirely possible for it to be able to migrate the schema over and into my db. I want to make it so that when I run my unit-tests locally it will run against this docker test container and not the public db.

Here is what I have so far, inside my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
db:
    image: mysql:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

When I run `docker-compose up` on my terminal, the container appears to build and is shown in the Docker UI. And when I run `docker ps` in another terminal I see the server is spun up.

Then when I go to MySQL workbench UI and login the credentials for the container as:

```
Username: localhost
Port: 3306
Password: test
Username: root
```

And when I run that I get a boiler-plate mysql db. Now what I want to do now is migrate the schema of another db to replace the boiler-plate one.

So I have flyway installed and everything setup on my machine but I don't know how to make the connection between that docker container db I just made and the db schema I have.

Here is my flyway file so far:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
flyway.user=root
flyway.password=test
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=false
flyway.defaultSchema=config_data
flyway.schemas=config_data, kol_data, baw_data, ter_data
```

I also think this layout I found online of the docker-compose.yaml file might work too but not sure how to integrate it into my code"

```
version: '3'
services:
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:6.3.1
    command: -configFiles=/flyway/conf/flyway.config -locations=filesystem:/flyway/sql -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/sql_versions:/flyway/sql
      - ${PWD}/docker-flyway.config:/flyway/conf/flyway.config
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=example-username
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    - POSTGRES_DB=db-name
```

All in all I simply want to take the schema from one db and put that into my docker container so that I can run unit-tests against it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you scripted out the other database into one or more migration scripts? They would go, based on your config, in the flyway/sql directory.